# firebase batch updates and onWrite trigger synchronisation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an issue with synchronizing two Firebase cloud functions, the first one performing a batch update on multiple documents and the second one triggered by an `onWrite` trigger on one of those documents.

For illustration, let us say I have two documents `A` and `B` (in two separate collections).

- A first cloud function updates both documents `A` and `B` with a firestore `WriteBatch` (both documents are successfully updated);
- The write in document `B` triggers another cloud function (with an `onWrite` trigger). This function needs to read document `A`;
- I have an error in this second function, that is because it read the old version of document `A` (before the write batch by the first function).

Is there a way to ensure the `onWrite` function is triggered **only after both documents have been written** ?

I could update them separately and await `A` to be written before I write `B` in the first function, but I want to keep the update of both in one transaction because these documents are linked, and I don't want to risk having one updated without the other.

Comment: Is the `onWrite` trigger for B only triggered when you update through the batched write or it can be triggered in other case? In other words, you could use maybe use a Cloud Function triggered with Pub/Sub and send a new Pub/Sub message when the batched write is completed.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Renaud! 

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes the `onWrite` for `B` can be triggered by other events, in practice `B` can also be directly updated by users of an app. Thanks for the hint, I will take a closer look at the Pub/Sub option. But for my information, isn't the batch write supposed to be instantaneous ? (doing all writes at the same time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A batched write ensures that **the writes are atomically completed**: if one write fails, the other ones are not executed. On the other hand, to answer to one of your comments above, a batched write does not ensure that all the writes will be "instantaneous", which, by the way, is a notion that is difficult to define in IT, IMHO :-). AFAIK, a batched write does not ensure neither that the writes will be done in the order they were pushed to the batch.

So, if you want to trigger the second Cloud Function when all the writes composing the batched write are completed, you could use a Cloud Function triggered with Pub/Sub.

Concretely, do as follows in your `index.js` Cloud Functions file:

Declare a function that publishes a message:

```js
async function publishMessage(messageConfig) {
    try {
        const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

        const topicName = messageConfig.topicName;
        const pubSubPayload = messageConfig.pubSubPayload;

        let dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(pubSubPayload));
        await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);

    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

In you Cloud Function that commits the batch, publish a message when the batched write is completed:

```js
    await batch.commit();
    
    messageConfig = {
          topicName: 'your-topic',
          pubSubPayload: {
              docA_Id: '..........',  // Id of doc A
              docB_Id: '..........'   // Id of doc B
          }
    }
    await publishMessage(messageConfig);
    // ...
```

Write a pub/sub triggered Cloud Function that executes the desired business logic. If the same business logic needs to be triggered with an `onWrite` trigger, share the code between the two functions

```js
    exports.updateDocB = functions.pubsub.topic('your-topic').onPublish(async (message) => {

       const docA_Id = message.json.docA_Id;   
       const docB_Id = message.json.docB_Id;   

       await updateDocB(docA_Id, docB_Id);
       // ...
    
    })


    async function updateDocB(docA_Id, docB_Id)  {
       // ......
    }
    // Call this function from the onWrite CF
```

If you want to avoid that the `onWrite` triggered Cloud Function is executed when the batched write is executed, you could flag docs A and B with the unique Cloud Function [`eventId`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#eventid) via the batched write. If this flag is the same in A and B you don't execute the business logic in the `onWrite` triggered Cloud Function, because it will be handled by the pub.sub Cloud Function.

---

Of course, this is based on several assumptions and has to cope with the flow of events but it could be a possible solution!

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer - very complete and informative, this will work very well !