# How to continue running Firebase Cloud Function after request is finished

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Really bizarre that Firebase doesn't seem to work quite like typical Express app. Whatever I write in Express and copy-paste to Firebase Functions I typically get error. There is one that I can't figure out on my own though.

This endpoint is designed to start a function and live long enough to finish even longer task. That request is a webhook (send docs, we will transform them and ping you when it's done to specified another webhook). Very simplified example below:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  try {
    generateZipWithDocuments(data) // on purpose it's not async so request can return freely
    res.sendStatus(201)
  
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({ error })
  }
})
```

On my local machine it works (both pure Express app and locally emulated Firebase Functions), but in the cloud it has problems and even though I put a cavalcade of `console.log()` I don't get much information. No error from Firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `generateZipWithDocuments()` is not asynchronous `res.sendStatus()` will be immediately executed after it, and **the Cloud Function will be terminated** (and the job done by `generateZipWithDocuments()` will not be completed). See the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?authuser=0) for more details.

You have two possibilities:

1. You make it asynchronous and you wait until its job is completed before sending the response. You would typically use `async/await` for that. Note that the maximum execution time for a Cloud Function is 9 minutes.
2. You delegate the long time execution job to another Cloud Function and, **then**, you send the response. For delegating the job to another Cloud Function, you should use Pub/Sub. See [Pub/Sub triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events?authuser=0), [the sample quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node/quickstarts/pubsub-helloworld), and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65816683/3371862) for more details on how to implement that. In the Pub/Sub triggered Function, when the job is done you can inform the user via an email, a [notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?authuser=0), the update of a Firestore document on which you have set a listener, etc... If `generateZipWithDocuments()` takes a long time, it is clearly the most user friendly option.

Comment: Using `async/await` might be a bit troublesome because some processed documents can take ~2GB (imagine thousands of documents created). In such situations I run into risk of timing out. Other thing, I want it to be connectable to third-party API's (like Zapier, Pabbly) so I also need to give user ability to specify to which endpoint should I send download link from Google Cloud Storage (where final file is updated). I'm just wrapping my head around Pub/Sub right now thanks to your links

Comment: You can very well pass some data from the first Cloud Function to the Pub/Sub one, see the third link. In any case, if you execute the job in a Cloud Function, **you must** use `async/await` (or `then()`) in order to correctly manage the life cycle of the Cloud Function, see the first link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will check all of that and get back after I will make it work. In the meantime: do you know maybe why it works locally without making any PubSub mechanism? I thought if it won't work on production then local env should also not work <confused>

Comment: Also those quota are confusing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas - PubSub function counts as background function? If so, in situation where users sends file over 10MB function won't work? Sorry for so many questions, docs are really not an easy read

Comment: @jeand'arme see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background. Since your new problem is separate from your original post, I suggest that you create a new question about it.

Comment: Look a the limits here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas => Message size (the data field): 10MB. You should not try to push large files to Cloud Functions and then to Pub/Sub messages. One approach would be to upload the file to Cloud Storage and pass its reference to the CFs. Now, as I've said above, the maximum execution time for a Cloud Function is 9 minutes. It may appear that Cloud Function is not a suitable solution for your need.