# Background processing with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I recently started seemingly similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834739/how-to-continue-running-firebase-cloud-function-after-request-is-finished), but I feel that maybe I implied too much in my question by asking how to implement something instead of asking how to solve specific problem. So here I go asking from different angle:

- third-party API (most possibly webhook) sends .csv file and .docx files (data and template) and sends response as fast as those files are uploaded (no waiting until those documents are processed)
- server merges that data and whenever the data is ready it sends to the user-specified endpoint response with download link
- I want to use Firebase products to achieve that
- it has to be compatible with typical automation tools like Zapier, Pabbly etc. (it just has to work like typical webhook)

In my previous question I got quite interesting answer to use PubSub (almost tried it, but got [error](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3073) while installing it), but I'm thinking - maybe there is some easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I wrote in my last comment to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65834739/3371862), if you plan to send heavy files to Cloud Functions, bear in mind that the size limit for data sent to an HTTP Cloud Functions is 10MB (See [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas?hl=bg)). There is the same limit for the size of messages you can push to Pub/Sub. (See [doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas)).

One approach would be to upload the files (data and template) to Cloud Storage and pass their references to the HTTP Cloud Function and, from this one, pass them in the payload of the Pub/Sub message (as explained in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65836027/3371862)). Then in the Pub/Sub Cloud Function, you read the files from Cloud Storage.

Comment: I must say I really admire how all your answers are to the point, with links and proper styling :) Now back to the answer: I think that approach you suggested seems to be the easiest to wrap a head around. From what I understand if I pass-through uploaded files (stream directly from the request?) then I will barely touch memory quota and use more of Cloud Storage?

Comment: Also when generating documents I probably can't stream it before I zip it so here I have to do it in memory and then I'm only limited to the "Max function memory" quota which is 4GB, correct?

Comment: Okay, I think I now understood that I can't upload data and template via HTTP Cloud Function which is precisely what I need because my webhook needs to accept files. Example: someone has automation service that downloads data from somewhere and turns into .csv file and then sends it over to my service. When it's done it sends further download link to generated documents.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to overcome the file limit is to use streams in cloud functions. Depending on your application you could stream your data directly back to the client (assuming you are using a http cloud function) / or a bucket. If you do this, your cloud function will only use a couple of mb. We did that with a quite large zip file containing averagely of 2-3 gb.

So this should work in your case.

Comment: Somewhere else I was told that because of the zip it won't be that easy and also streaming means there is no checksum and therefore guarantee that file will not be corrupted. Not sure what all that means, but maybe smarter heads here will :)